# groupby iterator not adding to list in dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a db query that returns a list.  I then do a a dictionary comprehension like so:

```
results = {product: [g for g in group] for product, group in groupby(db_results, lambda x: x.product_id)}
```

The problem is that the value of the dictionary is only returning 1 value. I assume this do to the fact that the group is an iterator.

The following returns each item of the group, so I know that they are there:

```
groups = groupby(db_results, lambda x: x.product_id)
for k,g in groups:
    if k==1001:
        print list(g)
```

I am trying to get all the values of g in the above in a list whose key is the key of dictionary.

I've tried many variations like:

```
blah = dict((k,list(v)) for k,v in groupby(db_results, key=lambda x: x.product_id))
```

but I can't get it right.

Comment: what is `db_results`?

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example with sample data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: `[g for g in group]` is not a reasonable list comprehension as you get the same result from a simple `list(group)`. Also `if k=1001:` is a `SyntaxError`, so you haven't shown us your real code.

Comment: db_results is a list of sqlalchemy objects.  I was trying [g for g in group] because I thought group was an iterator because when I looped over 'g' it returned iterator objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using `groupby`, then you need to make sure that the input is sorted byt the same key that you group on, however, I think I would suggest that you use `defaultdict` instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict
blah = defaultdict(list)
for item in db_results:
    blah[item.product_id].append(item)
```